# Laying out items in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, interface, interface-builder

So I haven't had problems with this before, but for some reason, my view seems to be shifted up. On my first view controller that I add to the subview, it seems to be shifted up 20 pixels, showing whitespace.  I am following the blue lines in interface builder, and I don't do any resizing or offsets with my view or frame.  I basically just alloc/init my subclass of UIViewController in my app delegate, and add the .view of that viewcontroller to my subview.  Just wondering if there might be something else I'm missing??? Sorry for being so vague, i just don't see what's going on.

Looking at the MkMapView I dropped into my view, it says the x, y is (0, 20), and the width/height is 320/460.  But again, for some reason it does not display properly in the iOS simualtor.

Answer (score 1):

On the main view, check the settings (View Attributes/Simulated User Interface Elements) for the status bar. That's probably the 20 px culprit.

I usually encounter this problem with 44 px, in which case the navigation bar is misbehaving.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's it seeing how I deleted the .xib file, and created a new one and still had the same problem.  I thought it might be something in my code, but I do not have any frames moving, CGRects, resizing going on... :-\

Comment: @Crystal: To test the theory, toggle the status bar in the IB. Turn it on, check the dimensions. Turn it off, check the dimensions. If the xib gets loaded before the status bar gets added/removed, then this is often the problem that results. The 20px is highly suspicious. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Still not working.  I removed the status bar from the window and view independently, and together.  When I run the app, the map is still offset by 20px and the status bar is showing on my simluator which i'm not sure why either.